# Array assignment for characters: C programming

Tags: c, arrays

Need help with array assignment

In my code i am declaring array as shown below.

```
u8 sendbuffer_1[4];
```

In my main, i am assigning it as shown below.

```
sendbuffer_1[] = {":K1\r"};
```

I tried removing the square brackets as well but doesn't work!!

Get error (with the square brackets)

```
../src/helloworld.c: In function 'main':
../src/helloworld.c:80:18: error: expected expression before ']' token
sendbuffer_1[] = {":K1\r"};
```

Error(Without square bracket)

```
../src/helloworld.c: In function 'main':
../src/helloworld.c:80:20: error: expected expression before '{' token
 sendbuffer_1 = {":K1\r"};
```

Please let me know the issue.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: One too short: you didn't allow for the `nul` terminator. `u8 sendbuffer_1[5] = ":K1\r";` or just `u8 sendbuffer_1[] = ":K1\r";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign arrays in C.  You can initialize them, but you can't assign them.

This is an initialization:

```
u8 sendbuffer_1[4] = {":K1\r"};
```

It wouldn't be legal in C++; it is in C but the `sendbuffer_1` array is not null terminated.  That's dangerous if you're expecting a string.

Otherwise, you'd use `memmove()` or something similar to set the array:

```
memmove(sendbuffer_1, ":K1\r", sizeof(sendbuffer_1));
```

Beware of the sizes of the source string (`":K1\r"`) and the destination string; the length copied should be the minimum of the two sizes.  That is, if `sendbuffer_1` was an 80-character buffer, the `memmove()` would not be safe, not because `sendbuffer_1` would be overflowed, but because you'd be accessing beyond the end of the string).  Be very careful in C.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!That

Comment: "Be very careful in C" +1.

Answer (score 0):

Either when initializing your array:

```
u8 sendbuffer_1[] = {":K1\r"};
```

Or if you need to assign these values in your main function you'll need to insert each value individually as follows:

```
sendbuffer_1[0] = ':';
sendbuffer_1[1] = 'K';    
sendbuffer_1[2] = '1';
sendBuffer_1[3] = '\r';
```